# Android Studio (1.5) hangs when using custom component

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use a custom component in my app. This is the code:

Layout file (select_method_layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/encabezadometodo"
    android:id="@+id/encabezadometodo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<es.infaplic.aguaics.Componentes.ComponenteSelectMethod
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/methodfile"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textexplicacion"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<es.infaplic.aguaics.Componentes.ComponenteSelectMethod
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/methodservice"
    android:layout_below="@+id/methodfile"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/layoutmethodservice"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/servicemethod"
        android:id="@+id/service"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/layoutmethodfile"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/layoutmethodservice">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/filemethod"
        android:id="@+id/file"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/textexplicacion"
    android:id="@+id/textexplicacion"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/encabezadometodo"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

The class that controls the custom component:

```
public class ComponenteSelectMethod extends RelativeLayout {

private ImageView imagen;
private TextView text;

public ComponenteSelectMethod(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inicializar();
}

public ComponenteSelectMethod(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    inicializar();
}

private void inicializar() {
    String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater li =
            (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(infService);
    li.inflate(R.layout.componente_select_method_layout, this, true);
    imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageiconoselectmethod);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmethod);
}

public void setImage(int icono){
    this.imagen.setBackgroundResource(icono);
}

public void setText(String text){
    this.text.setText(text);
}
}
```

And, in the main class, I am using it this way:

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.firsttime));
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_method_layout, null);
        dialog.setView(dialoglayout);
        ComponenteSelectMethod cFile=(ComponenteSelectMethod)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.methodfile);
        ComponenteSelectMethod cService=(ComponenteSelectMethod)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.methodservice);
        LinearLayout layoutFile=(LinearLayout)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.layoutmethodfile);
        LinearLayout layoutService=(LinearLayout)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.layoutmethodservice);
        cFile.setImage(R.drawable.icono_archivo_agu);
        cFile.setText(getString(R.string.textexplicacionfile));
        cService.setImage(R.drawable.icono_directorio);
        cService.setText(getString(R.string.textexplicacionservice));
        final AlertDialog methodDialog=dialog.show();
        layoutFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settings.edit().putString("method", "file").apply();
                methodDialog.dismiss();
                proceder();
            }
        });
        layoutService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settings.edit().putString("method", "service").apply();
                methodDialog.dismiss();
                proceder();
            }
        });
```

EDIT:

componente_select_method_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageiconoselectmethod"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textmethod"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageiconoselectmethod"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageiconoselectmethod"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this, when I open the xml file, it fails rendering. It stays in "Rendering..." and does nothing more. If I access the Text mode in layout editing, and do anything (like hitting space bar) Android Studio stops responding.

Is something wrong with my custom component? Anybody knows how to avoid Android Studio to hang?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you manualy choose the Theme in the layout xml previewer ? Bugs tend to happen to me if I don't (try Holo light for instance), but I don't really understand why...

Comment: I touched nothing there. Generated the file, dragged the components...and this happened.

Comment: I can't even exit Android Studio. Have to force close it...

Comment: Have tried what you suggested, and nothing happened. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please share layout : `select_method_layout`

Comment: Its in the question. If you mean the component layout, will update in a moment.